# Efficient way to multiply string

Tags: c++, string, optimization

http://ideone.com/g7rGS7

As you can see it exceeds the time limit.

Somebody gave me the idea of having 10 or so static variables of empty spaces and concatenating them to form bigger spaces, and so I wanted to try to do it by doing powers of 2. The code works, but it's obviously very slow. What's a faster way of doing this?

```cpp
std::string operator*(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    std::string r;
    r.reserve(n * s.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        r += s;
    return r;
}

std::string operator^(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    std::string r = s;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        r = s * r.size();
    }
    if (n == 0) return std::string(" ");
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    string blank = " ";
    string blank2 = blank * 2;
    string blank4 = blank2 ^ 2;
    string blank8 = blank2 ^ 3;
    string blank16 = blank2 ^ 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        assert((blank2 ^ i).size() == pow(2, i));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Exponentation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I just reread your question and it occurs to me that I might have misunderstood what you are trying to do in my answer below. Are you trying to implement the multiplication or the exponentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259164/efficient-way-to-multiply-string/18259503#comment26778361_18259164), you can do something like this:

```
std::string str_double (std::string const & s)
{
    return s + s;
}

std::string operator*(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    return str_double(s * (n / 2)) + ((n % 2) ? s : std::string());
}
```

I believe it's quite efficient if your compiler and standard library support rvalue references and moving.

However, I don't think anything will be much faster than the straightforward version, like so:

```
std::string operator*(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    std::string r;
    r.resize (n * s.size()); // note resizing, not reserving
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i, j += s.size())
        memcpy (&(r[j]), &(s[0]), s.size());
    return r;                
}
```

Comment: @remyabel: I don't understand what the problem is that you are mentioning. However, the second code had a compiler error that is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator^ does a lot of string allocation.  The operator* pre-allocates the string, which is good, but your operator^ creates an intermediate string every time it calls operator*.  Instead, pre-calculate the length of r, and the number of copies required.  Then you can pre-allocate r and perform the concatenations without creating a bunch of unneeded strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fill it with 1 character (the space in your example), the way to make them faster is to eliminate the for-loops altogether:

```
int main()
{
    string blank2(2, ' ');
    string blank4(4, ' ');
    string blank8(8, ' ');
    string blank16(16, ' ');

    // etc

    return 0;
}
```

To make it generic (so you can do this with more than just 1 character), you'll still want to limit your loops:

```
std::string operator*(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    std::string r(n * s.size(), ' '); // initialize the string with the needed size
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) // O(n)
        r += s;
    return r;
}

std::string operator^(std::string const &s, size_t n)
{
    size_t sn = std::pow(s.size(), n);
    std::string r(sn, ' ');
    for (size_t i = 1; i < sn; i++) // since this doesn't have an inner loop in the * operator, it is O(n) instead of O(n^2)
    {
        r += s;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    string blank = " ";
    string blank2 = blank * 2;
    string blank4 = blank2 ^ 2;
    string blank8 = blank2 ^ 3;
    string blank16 = blank2 ^ 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        assert((blank2 ^ i).size() == pow(2, i));

    return 0;
}
```